# A condition that checks for A or B but not Both

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I have a conditional in plain javascript that checks for A or B

```
const A = true
const B = true

if (A || B) {
  return 'X'
}
```

## Problem

I want to change this to check for A  or B but not an both. So if both match then don't return X.

---

Please direct me to a similar question if it's already been answered. I'm having trouble phrasing my search. I'm just getting SQL and regex answers.

Comment: Sounds like a XOR, which you can mimic with a != b in most programming languages.

Comment: can you spell it out for me please, how do I phrase it to get the conditional to pass all three conditions in the if statement?

Comment: If you downvote this question or want it closed please explain why and I will try and improve the question. This is a deceptively simple question and I've been banging my head against it for half an hour. Please help.

Comment: @404 I have updated the question to clarify, please let me know if it is clearer now.

Comment: `I want to change this to check for nameMatch or emailMatch but not an nameMatch and an emailMatch` that's literally written as `(a || b) && !(a && b)`

Comment: It's not exactly clear what truth table you need. Can you answer the following questions: should X be returned if nameMatch is false and emailMatch is false? If nameMatch is false and emailMatch is true? If nameMatch is true and emailMatch is false? If nameMatch is true and emailMatch is true? This will help building the truth table you need, then we can help finding the right boolean operator(s).

Comment: it would be easier if you add a table of truth for `a`, `b` and the wanted result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take either

```
if (!a || !b) {
    // your code
}
```

or the equivalent of using [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

```
if (!(a && b)) {
    // your code
}
```

Table of truth:

| a | b | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| false | false | true |
| false | true | true |
| true | false | true |
| true | true | false |

Comment: This is the best implementation now - OP only wants false under one condition, so no need to check anything other than that one condition, i.e. that both aren't true.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
const A = true
const B = true

if ((A || B) && (A != B)) {
  return 'X'
}
```

Comment: The `A || B` is redundant, but the logic is correct.

Comment: This doesn't work because if both conditions are false then it does not return X. I'm updating my question with an example and removing pseudo to make it clearer.

Answer (score -2):

This is an EXOR Implementation which can be done in the following way.

```
const A = true
const B = true

if ( A != B)) {
  return 'X'
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer op's question. They want true if A == true || B == true but not if A && B == true

Comment: So you want an opposite of AND if I am not understanding wrong?

Comment: You have misunderstood.